# Java Chat Multi-Client Receiving thread

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, chat

In a lot of multclient java programs people use a separate thread which only receives the messages from the server. Is it really necessary? Why can't it be done in the main thread? What should be the problem?

For me a separate thread to receive the messages from the server is not that necessary, it could be done simply be the main.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it's not necessary?

Comment: Because the swing methods are invoked in event dispatch thread. So it'd never stop my loop which is receiving messages from servers. And also, we are talking about sockets and streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 6 years I would like to answer myself of the past.

Some more context: the multi-client chat is a GUI chat that used swing. It was a high school project.

The main method would go in a loop to read messages received from a server. Since every other client action is event-based, the event handling would be done on a separate thread anyway.

So yeah, it worked fabulously at the time!

Answer (score 0):

No, if it was done in the main method, then the rest of your application would wait until a message is received. This may be fine if your application only received messages. However, if your application did other things like accepting user input in order to send messages then, the application would not be able to do the other tasks(such as user Input) until a message has been received.

EDIT:

It would also have a hard time with multiple clients

Comment: But the input is managed by the swing through the event dispatch thread. What should be the problem? Do u mean that the message could delay? So is this delay long? Are we talking about seconds? Or ms?

Comment: The input was just an example. If there are multiple clients then the second message would only be recognized after the first message is recognized-This is what I meant by delay. SO, I would advise you to use multi-threading and not just put it all in the main.

Comment: But even If i have a separate thread which reads the Messages, the problem will not Change. The reatina will be sequenziale. And the multiclient aspect is managed by the server not by the client. So for a client it is transparent.

Comment: Ok, maybe I understood. So If my main only reads it is not necessary to create a separate thread, but If the main has other tasks it will cause a delay of some ms in viewing the message on the client. right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also, if the answer has answered your question then, feel free to select it :)

Comment: Oh I did not specify that the messages would be received only from one server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. At least if you want something pratical.
If you get updates periodical, you need to wait every x ms/s/mins for the server input to be read, if you receive message from the server directly you need to wait everytime someone sends one, and could not even handle multiple messages at once.

Now add a Graphical Interface and youll run into a wall trying to handle that by 1 thread.

Not that it would make sense anyway.

Comment: But all the other threads related to the gui is processed by the event dispatch thread. The main would never be stopped. And what does change if it is a multi client?

Comment: On receiving data from multiple clients at once, you never would be able to read all of them because one read would block the thread so you can not read the others. (with reading I mean receiving data)

Comment: Blocking the thread it will make a delay. Ho muchi is this delay? 1 ms? If so it is acceptable.